# Taking HDMI input on a laptop running Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: python, software-recommendation, hardware, hdmi

I have a [Panoview sports camera](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/panoview-xdv360-sports-camera-wifi.html?___store=en_us).

I am trying to connect it to my laptop through its HDMI port.
Is there any software/python module to capture its feed?

Comment: According to the description the HDMI must connect to your TV. Just as you use the HDMI of your laptop to connect to the TV. In other words your laptop and your camera have HDMI OUTPUT ports, not input ports. You could try to use the Wifi capabilities of the camera to connect to with your laptop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that HDMI ports on any laptop is output only.
No driver nor script may be able to capture video from here.

If the devices supports it, it can maybe output some data via the usb.

You may also try a device like [avermedia ones](http://www.avermedia.com/) to do such thing, but it is an expensive solution.